# Webscraping with Goutte and Guzzle

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, goutte

I have the following method from my controller that gets the data from the site:

```php
$goutteClient = new Client();
$guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient([
   'timeout' => 60,
]);
$goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);
$crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Laravel');
$crawler->filter('.result__title .result__a')->each(function ($node) {
    dump($node->text());
});
```

The above code gives me the title of contents from the search results. I also want to get the link of the corresponding search result. That resides in class `result__extras__url`.

How do I filter the link in and the title at once? Or do I have to run another method for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to inspect the attributes of the nodes. Once you get the `href` attribute, parse it to get the URL.

```php
$crawler->filter('.result__title .result__a')->each(function ($node) {
    $parts = parse_url(urldecode($node->attr('href')));
    parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
    $url = $params['uddg']; // DDG puts their masked URL and places the actual URL as a query param.
    $title = $node->text();
});
```

Comment: How do I pass data to view ?? The `title` and `url` variable is only accessible inside `each `function

Comment: Declare an array outside the `each` callback. Pass it to the `each` callback by reference. Populate the array with the data you need from within the callback.

Comment: Yeha I did but it has some issue. I've posted it here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62779720/push-to-data-to-array-and-pass-to-view-view-laravel

Comment: You passed the array directly, instead pass it by reference, like `... use(&$a) { ...` then it will point to the same array instead of a clone.

Answer (score 1):

For parsing, I usually do the following:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML((string)$crawler->getBody());
```

from then on, you can access using `getElementsByTagName` functions on your DOMDocument.

for example:

```
$rows = $doc->getElementsByTagName('tr');
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $cols = $row->getElementsByTagName('td');
    $value = trim($cols->item(0)->nodeValue);
}
```

You can find more information in
https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Where do I find the description of `getElementsByTagName` functions. Can't find them on the docs. Need to see what other methods are available

Comment: I added the official php documentation link