# Push the guzzle response data to array and pass it to view in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle, goutte

I have the following method from my controller to scrap a data from a url:

```js
    public function fetchFromUrl(Request $request)
    {
        $a =[];
        $goutteClient = new Client();
        $guzzleClient = new GuzzleClient([
            'timeout' => 60,
            'verify' => false
        ]);
        $goutteClient->setClient($guzzleClient);
        $crawler = $goutteClient->request('GET', 'https://html.duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Laravel');

        $crawler->filter('.result__title .result__a')->each(function ($node) use($a){
             $parts = parse_url(urldecode($node->attr('href')));
             parse_str($parts['query'], $params);
             $url = $params['uddg']; 
             array_push($a, $url);
                
            dump($url);
            //$title = $node->text();
        });
        dump($a);
        //return view('view')->withDatas($a);
    }
```

With the above method execution I want to push the extracted data `$url` to the array $a and pass it to the view. But all I get is an empty array.

I also want to push `$title` to new array and do the same. But the first one is not working so I've commented it out.

Answer (score 0):

The `$a` array is being utilized within multiple scopes.  When used within the "inner scope" (within `each()`) it is copied into the function. The intent is to utilize the `$a` array by reference within the "inner scope".  This is completed by utilizing the ampersand `&`

```
$crawler->filter($filter_string)
        ->each(function($node) use ($a) {
...
```

Can be replaced with:

```
$crawler->filter($filter_string)
        ->each(function($node) use (&$a) {
```